Coldfusion application Scope variable
I have an application scope variable defined in my Application.cfm file
<!--- Application.cfm --->
<cfset application.calendar = "true">

Then in my main.cfm file, I have a button that the user will click which calls a cfc defined method that will update the application.calendar value to false.
main.cfm
$.get('./utility.cfc?method=setVal',function(){
    console.log(<cfoutput>"#application.calendar#"</cfoutput>);
})

Here is the cfc function
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="setVal" access="remote" returntype="any">
    <cftry>
            <cfset application.calendar = 'false'>
         
        <cfcatch >
            <p>Error on logout,try again later.</p><cfabort>
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
    <cfreturn application.calendar>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

When the console log runs, the value of application.calendar is still true. Just need some help to understand why this is. I saw some post recommending using application.cfc approach to have more control but just want to understand why this does not work.

You are returning application variable value, but you are not logging the response.
function(response){console.log(<cfoutput>"#application.calendar#"</cfoutput>)} this should be changed to function(response){console.log(response.data);}.
But the main problem is on next request, your application.cfm will overwrite this again with "True". That is why application.cfc is preferred as there are different event handlers like request start, application start etc.

In this instance, you might replace <cfset application.calendar = "true"> with <cfparam name="application.calendar" default="true">.  That way if the variable isn't defined yet, it will get defined with the default value of "true"; if the variable is already defined then it won't alter the value.

As @rrk said, it will get overwritten because application.cfm is run for each request. Maybe use the session scope instead? Also, perhaps start using modern coldfusion code, like application.cfc instead, and setting a Boolean value of true instead of a string value. Modern coldfusion syntax is a lot like JavaScript.

Thanks all, I got it. I will change over to cfc to get the desired functionality. Guess I miss understood that application.cfm run again on all request.

Are you sure that application is an appropriate scope?  It means that User 2 gets whatever User 1 set as the value.

Summarizing the comments:
When main.cfm is rendered to the browser, you have written out the value of application.calendar at the time of the rendering. Since the value in Application.cfm is true, the JavaScript rendered on the page will always be true.
Your main.cfm CFML code:
$.get('./utility.cfc?method=setVal',function(){
    console.log(<cfoutput>"#application.calendar#"</cfoutput>);
})

The rendered HTML:
$.get('./utility.cfc?method=setVal',function(){
    console.log("true");
})

But when the page is reloaded, the value of application.calendar will again be set to true. Changing to Application.cfc and setting this value in onApplicationStart() would help avoid this issue.
To @rrk's point, you need to log the response from the get() and not the value of the application variable at the time the page is rendered.
To @Dan's point, an application scoped variable is a global variable for the application's life. All users will see this value, and allowing each user to change it affects all other users as they render the page.
If this is meant to be a "user setting", then this value should be a session scoped variable. I would also save the value to the database when the user clicks the button in order to save the setting for the next time the user logs into the application.
